# Pancakeswap trade fee - When is it taken ? (Liquidity pool don't show it)

Tags: pancakeswap, fees, swaps

I can't find how/when [PancakeSwap take it 0.25% fee from trades](https://docs.pancakeswap.finance/products/pancakeswap-exchange/trade), Nothing points to it taking any fees!

**What I tried:**

-Fetched my bnb balance.

-Fetched Liquidity pool of a token.

-Made a buy transaction.

-Fetched Liquidity pool of a token again.

-Fetched my bnb balance again.

**Data:**

-Initial BNB balance: 0.061694940013323232

-After buy transaction: 0.060829815013323232 (Buy 0.00001 + Gas 0.000855125)

-Token address: 0xc709878167ed069aea15fd0bd4e9758ceb4da193 (Day Of Defeat 19% TAX)

-Buy transaction: https://bscscan.com/tx/0xa660eb5e16d872e29bf7caf7d7c5ef999a36cfdb488c05c1554587543d7151cf

-Initial LP: 4306.338723965573665600 BNB 1793846330848.225230596341489117 DOD

-After transaction LP: 4306.338733965573665600 BNB 1793846326693.044169436006428854 DOD

-Received tokens: 4155.181061160335060263 - 19% TAX = 3365.696659539871398814 DOD

**Math:**

LP BNB DIFF: 4306.338733965573665600 - 4306.338723965573665600 = 0.00001

LP TOKEN DIFF: 1793846330848.225230596341489117 - 1793846326693.044169436006428854 = 4155.181061160335060263

As you can see swap fee no where to be seen...

So my question is, When does PancakeSwap take it 0.25% fee from trades ?

Answer (score 1):

I asked the question in Reddit and got a response.

> ezmonkey
>
> Took me some time.The fee is already included in all the transactions.
> When you put in 0.00001 BNB and the contract decides to give you 4155
> DOD, that amount that it decides to spit out reflects the 0.25% fee.
> If there was no fee, the contract would have decided to give you
> instead 4165. This would be the case if the calculation was a simple k
> = tok1balance * tok2balance, but it is changed to reflect the fee.
>
> ```
> // if fee is on, mint liquidity equivalent to 8/25 of the growth in sqrt(k)
> function _mintFee(uint112 _reserve0, uint112 _reserve1) private returns (bool feeOn) { 
>     address feeTo = IPancakeFactory(factory).feeTo();
>     feeOn = feeTo != address(0);
>     uint _kLast = kLast; // gas savings
>     if (feeOn) {
>         if (_kLast != 0) { 
>             uint rootK = Math.sqrt(uint(_reserve0).mul(_reserve1));
>             uint rootKLast = Math.sqrt(_kLast);
>             if (rootK > rootKLast) { 
>                 uint numerator = totalSupply.mul(rootK.sub(rootKLast)).mul(8); 
>                 uint denominator = rootK.mul(17).add(rootKLast.mul(8)); 
>                 uint liquidity = numerator / denominator;
>                 if (liquidity > 0) 
>                     _mint(feeTo, liquidity);
>             }
>         } 
>     } else if (_kLast != 0) { 
>         kLast = 0; 
>     }
> }
> ```
>
> from
> https://bscscan.com/address/0xf26d328178cf6f011a3150dfe0282ff0f7c33a27#code

[Source](https://www.reddit.com/r/pancakeswap/comments/ssxe5a/comment/hx2fsao/?context=3)